# I need to customize tabBar

Tags: xcode, customization, uitabbar, tabbar

In my project I have two Views with TabBar and I would like to customize each one with different images.

Can anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Do you want to change the icon in the tab bar, or the background image in the view?

Comment: I want to change the background. Have two diferents backgrounds in the same projects. Because one has 4 items and the others has 5.

Comment: On my way to work.  Will post an answer in a bit.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wishing to customize the tabs in your tab bar, that can done by creating a UITabBarItem using the init method below and assigning it to the tabBarItem property of each navigation controller that goes into your tab bar controller. This will display the given titles and images on each tab.

```
navigationController.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"title"
                                      image:[UIImage imageNamedB:@"tabImage.png"]
                                        tag:0];
```

Comment: Thaks Patrick, but what i want to change is the background. I want to have two diferent backgrounds in the same projects.

Answer (score 0):

Osvaldo,  If you want two different backgrounds for the two different view controllers of your tab bar project you have a couple of options.  But I would do the following.  Grab a UIView from the object library and place one in each vc so that it fills the whole view.  Next you can place UIImageViews in the UIView you just placed.  Four in the one vc and five in the other.  Place them and size them to however you wish.  You then need to import the pictures you want to place in them.  Drag the image files into the left pane, the project outline.  Make sure you copy to destination so they are a part of your project.  Next in the vc's click on the UIImageView that you want the picture in.  On the right pane under attributes there will be a drop down menu called image.  Select the image you want and it will appear in the storyboard in the vc.  Do this for all the UIImageViews that you have.  When on storyboards, you can pop out the storyboard outline.  Make sure the UIImageViews are within the UIView.  Then select the UIView in the outline and go up to the editor menu, and select arrange, send to back.  It may be grayed out if the UIView was the only thing you had on the vc in the beginning.  So now, this UIView will act as a background, and you can customize them to look like anything you like.  Hope this helps, let us know how it goes.  If it works, please accept my answer, any other questions, just ask.

Comment: @Osvaldo Cipriano, How did it work out?  Was this what you were looking for?